# Problem while persisting the existing parent object into the child object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a existing table Action with pre-populated data and I am trying to save an object Stop which has the Action.Id as the foreign key. Below is my code that I tried. But in the Stop table the reference is not getting saved even though there are no error.

```
  public class Stop {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACTION_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Action action;
}
```

```
public class Action {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ACTION_ID")
    private String actionId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACTION_ID")
    private Stop stops;
}
```

I tried explicitly calling the `Optional<Action> action = actionRepo.findByActionId("ARRIVE")` and setting to the stop object. But it is not saving with the reference.

Answer (score 0):

After setting a new value to the JPA object you need to call save

```
Optional<Action> action = actionRepo.findByActionId("ARRIVE");
    if (action.isPresent()){
    actionRepo.save(action.get().setActionName("balal"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the @JoinColumn annotation from the Action class.  You don't typically need it on both sides.

```
public class Stop {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACTION_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Action action;
}

public class Action {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ACTION_ID")
    private String actionId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Stop stops;
}
```

Comment: solved it by removing the updatable = false, insertable = false and 
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="action")
    private Stop stops;